# Using IJSRuntime inside a Singleton service in blazor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service, blazor

My blazor project has a service from which I need to call a JavaScript function. The Problem is that I can't inject IJSRuntime into the service because it is a Singleton and IJSRuntime is scoped.

```
private readonly IJSRuntime _jsruntime;
public MyService(IJSRuntime jsruntime)
{
    _jsruntime = jsruntime;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work but does anyone know a way around it besides changing my service to scoped? I already tried this article: https://samwalpole.com/using-scoped-services-inside-singletons but I get an Error when calling InvokeVoidAsync.

**Edit:**

```
using CobotUI.Data;
using CobotUI.Data.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Radzen;
using System.Globalization;

//comment when local
//var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
//{
//    ApplicationName = typeof(Program).Assembly.FullName,
//    ContentRootPath = Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()),
//    WebRootPath = "wwwroot",
//    Args = args
//});

//uncomment when local
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<FarinoCommunicationService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StatusBarService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ShelveService, ShelveService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SettingsService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MessageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CobotService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoggingService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LightController>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBA>();

//comment when local
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    //app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
  {
    new CultureInfo("de"),
    new CultureInfo("en")
  };

var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(options);

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

//comment when local
//app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:80");

//uncomment when local
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using @inject (or [Inject]) for Blazor?

E.g.:

In .razor:

```
@inject IJSRuntime _jsruntime
```

In .razor.cs for separate code file or for code{} section:

```
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
```

Comment: My service is a plain .cs file. I tried the second option but JSRuntime is null unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share your program.cs?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I added the Program.cs to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a serviceprovider in your service. This way you can access the transient IJSRuntime instance in a service method.

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
public MyService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
public async Task OpenInWindow(string url)
{
    await serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>().InvokeVoidAsync("open", url, "_blank");
}
```